# How can I lower wifi transmit power below 0?

Tags: wifi, hostapd

We have a Pi 4 in a box with some other equipment, and it turns out that the wifi of the Pi is interfering with the other equipment. This is a problem because it can't be removed from the box it's in, and we need its wifi enabled.

The Pi is running `hostapd` to create its own wifi network that other devices (laptops, smartphones, etc) connect to. Right now, the wifi bubble the Pi creates is really big, giving us a far great range then we need, so the simple solution seems to be to just lower the tx power of the wifi on the Pi.

Lowering the tx power seems as simple as just doing:

```bsh
iw wlan0 set txpower fixed N
```

The strange thing is that settings this to 0, which we can verify with:

```bsh
$ iw wlan0 info
Interface wlan0
...
    txpower 0.00 dBm
```

Still lets us connect to the Pi's wifi from 100 feet away, and through a wall, with full bars. Using a wifi analyzer on my phone, I can however tell that the signal IS weaker at 0 dBm then at the default 31 dBm, and it's definitely not interfering with the other equipment nearly as much.

My question is this: is there a way to lower it even further? The command doesn't like negative numbers.

Comment: reading [documentation](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw#setting_tx_power) - `txpower`  sets the tx power - in millibel-milliwats - you can't have negative power, that would imply that transmitting would receive power rather than use power :p

Comment: @Bravo dBm is a logarithmic scale, and -ve values are common!

Comment: @Milliways - yes ... indeed ... never seen txpower negative though

Comment: Apparently, while it conceptually makes sense to have negative numbers on a logarithmic scale, when used for tx power, 1 dB is 1mW, which is very tiny, so normally, there's no need for negative numbers. The bigger problem appears to be that when I set it to 1dB, or 0dB, I can still connect to it from 100 feet away, suggesting it's not really set for 1mW, or anywhere near that. Is there something that is setting a minimum tx power level in Linux that is overriding the setting in this command?